# Animations of modal and dropdown in React Semantic UI

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I recently made the switch over to React Semantic-UI  However, I found that none of the animations in the HTML version of Semantic-UI are present such as with the dropdown menu and modal popup.

I have tried using the transition prop and wrapping it around a modal, but to no avail.

```
<Transition animation='scale' duration={500}>
  <Modal
    trigger={<Button>Show Modal</Button>}
    header='Reminder!'
    content='Call Benjamin regarding the reports.'
    actions={[
      'Snooze',
      { key: 'done', content: 'Done', positive: true },
    ]}
  />
</Transition>
```

Is there any way do fix this?

Comment: Transition component is done, however transitions for all components are still in work. Follow, https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/pull/2001

Comment: @AlexanderFedyashov So is there no way to implement the transitions at the moment, even with the transition component?

Comment: In fact, yes. All components are too complicated to do this, except Accordion.

Answer (score 5):

There's quite a few solutions with examples given in the following discussion. I've tried wrapping the `<Modal>` with `<TransitionablePortal>` and it works. Check it out:
https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/2923

Comment: any similar solution for dropdown?